# Bug in showing progress towards badges?

Tags: bug, badges, design

Someone on Math.StackExchange got the `Informed` badge several hours ago, but it still shows 1/1 for Informed:

[image]

This is weird, because normally, the next badge already says that you got it while you didn't get it already. It is also weird that after several hours, it hasn't been fixed if it was catching.

I've found several cases of this on Math.SE and StackOverflow. It also happens in the Autobiographer badge where the badge was awarded 15h ago.

Comment: It could be because of Cache... I have seen this question before.

Comment: @HackerKarma Caching after six hours? I've now also found an instance where it hasn't been changed even though the badge was awarded thirteen hours ago.

Comment: And that one does not have answer either.

Comment: Some scripts only run once a day and I have seen reports that the tag update script doesn't run so maybe more scripts are affected due to that.

Comment: @rene I wonder why no one is posting an answer for this and that.

Comment: @HackerKarma if the SRE team needs to answer every post about a glitch in the operation they probably spend more time answering then keeping the sites running. That doesn't mean though that these bug reports are not welcome.

Comment: @rene Agree. by "no one" I mean someone from community members. I think it is worth to post answer to avoid future dupes.

Comment: That could be true but answering this would be mere speculation IMHO, so I'm not sure if that is helpful but don't hold back if you see fit.

Comment: @rene Well one could post an answer like: "The bug was solved". That takes only a minute.

Comment: Sure, but given the size of the bug backlog (being over 4000 last time I saw a glimpse of it) that would take 4000 minutes... that is almost 2 weeks of work for one person...

Comment: Missed the original version. I'm gonna go ahead and mark this as a dupe, but I'll ask a dev to see if we can repro, and I'll put a note on the other one to that effect.  (Since I can see how annoying it'd be to have this marked dupe of something with no response.)